# Streaming very large json directly from a POST request in Django

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, streaming

I'm looking for efficient ways to handle very large json files (i.e. possibly several GB in size, amounting to a few million json objects) in requests to a Django 2.0 server (using Django REST Framework). Each row needs to go through some processing, and then get saved to a DB.

The biggest painpoint thus far is the sheer memory consumption of the file itself, and the memory consumption steadily still increasing while the data is being processed in Django, without any ability to manually release the memory used.

Is there a recommended way of processing very large json files in requests to a Django app, without slaughtering memory consumption? Possible to combine with compressing (gzip)? I'm thinking of uploading the json to the API as a regular file, stream that to disk, and then stream from the file on disk using ijson or similar? Is there a more straightforward way?

Comment: My inclination would be to use `ijson` and `csv` to write csv files and import those directly into the database. The ORM is bulky and gets in the way.